# Time Series Prediction with Prophet

Tags: python, date, forecast, facebook-prophet

I've been working on time series forecasting with PROPHET, I'm facing an issue with `future= prophet_basic.make_future_dataframe(periods=61)`i want to predict the sales for the coming 61 days but the code keeps skipping dates such as shown in the image:
[Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpa0q.png)

after 7th of November the code stops skipping dates and return all the days in December.

Thank you!